# OnActivityResult Listener is not called

Tags: android, zxing

Could someone please help me to understand and solve why the OnActivityResultListener is not called in the below code, I have checked the error log and i am not able to find the solution

**MainActivity**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Handling multiple scan modes based on selection
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
if (type == "QR_CODE_MODE"){
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
}else if(type == "PRODUCT_MODE"){
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
}else {
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,PDF417,RSS_EXPANDED");
}
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}


public void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //we have a result
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + contents);
            contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + format);
        }
     else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
         formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: No results found");
         contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: No results found");
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Scan was Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
         toast.show();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the OnActivityResultListener is not called

Because `OnActivityResultListener` (is a interface in [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener.html)) is not an method which call in parent Activity when child Activity finish.

You can get result in parent Activity by implementing `OnActivityResultListener` in parent Activity and by overriding `onActivityResult` as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...do your work here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer yar, but i am not able to get clearly. Do you want me to define the onActivityResult inside the parent onActivityResultListener?

Comment: @RazerWaran: instead of `onActivityResultListener` method use `onActivityResult` and this method is already in Activity you just need to override in same way as we override onCreate,onResume...

Comment: If i try to override i am getting error like "this type should override a subtype method"

Comment: Thanks a lot yar, when i copied a code and it got Overrided :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public void OnActivityResultListener(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
```

to

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
```

[onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) is a method you can override in Activity, and the `@Override` can automatically check if the method does override a method in a supertype.

Comment: Thanks for answer yar, I tried but it is not working

Comment: It should be a lowercase **on**ActivityResult().